How could China benefit from formally joining the MTCR?
China expressed intent to formally join the  Missile Technology Control Regime MTCR but was reportedly rebuffed.
Besides the obvious benefits of them joining like some slight boost to their international standing and [perhaps] being privy to some discussions they weren't [privy] to before, is there some non-obvious benefit for China joining the MTCR? Could they e.g. veto some important decisions there? (Wikipedia says "The MTCR is not a treaty and does not impose any legally binding obligations on partners"-- so the benefits [for China joining] aren't too obvious.)

Wikipedia says China has been adhering to the rules since 1991, so I guess the question is less why they want to formally join than why they have voluntarily followed its rules.

@StuartF: honestly the latter Q is easier to answer: Western pressure. Which was certainly more effective in the '90s. Yeah, I really want to know what they hope to gain by formally joining.
